# How do I control execution of Maven Jetty Plugin with -Dmaven.test.skip

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty

I am using [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to automate some unit tests from my [Maven 2](http://maven.apache.org). We only really want to run these tests as part of the CI build and would like to control it via the `-Dmaven.test.skip` property.

I cannot find a way to apply this to the executions for the Jetty plugin. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you clarify:  Are you trying to run all your integration tests only on the CI server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven.test.skip property is a property that the surefire plugin looks at to decide if it should just skip. The jetty plugin doesn't care at all about this property. The only way to do this would move your jetty plugin execution to a profile and try [activating](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) it if the maven.test.skip property is false.

Comment: This doesn't work if the -Dmaven.test.skip is omitted. It means that the solution is to create a profile specifically for the CI server and specify that as part of the build instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Feature request about this capability already fixed and now you can skip jetty plugin execution by setting `jetty.skip` property:

```
$ mvn -Djetty.skip=true
```

See also:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin#Skipping_execution_of_jetty
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1051

Answer (score -1):

see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin

Comment: This link just refers me to the documentation which does not actually cover the use case.

Comment: hmm there is the automatic execution example (as part of test process) and if there is no test process (with -skip...) well then there is no jetty startup for it